# How to sequentially load images in React Native, one after another, when passing an object with an array of multiple images?

Tags: javascript, react-native, image, web, expo

I'm working on a React Native project and facing a challenge with loading images sequentially. Specifically, I need to load images one after another in a strict order when passing an object with an array containing multiple images.

Here's a simplified example of my code structure:

1. The first component renders a list of items using a `FlatList`. Each item has an associated array of images:

```
const renderItem = ({ item, i }) => (
  <ObservationItem
    // ... other props
  />
);

<FlatList
  contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: '10%' }}
  data={dataWithImages}
  renderItem={renderItem}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
/>

The second component renders images and is used within the first component. The renderImage function handles image rendering based on certain conditions:
function renderImage(imageItem, status, style) {
  // ... image rendering logic
 if (imageItem && (imageItem.s3Id || imageItem.imageFile || imageItem.image)) {
      return (
        <View transparent>
                <Image
                  source={{
                    uri: `http://localhost:44348/api/Images/ResizeImage,
                  }}
                  PlaceholderContent={<ActivityIndicator color="#008000" />}
                  style={style}
                />
</View>
 );
  }
  return null;
}

// ... rendering images for each item and subItem

<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: status >= 40 && 'space-evenly' }}>
          {item.images.slice(0, 2).map((image, index) => (
            image !== null && (
              <View key={index} style={{ marginRight: status >= 40 && index === 0 ? 20 : 0 }}>
                {renderImage(image, status, 
                    {
                      height: status >= 40 ? 150 : 120,
                      width: status >= 40 ? 180 : 133,
                      marginRight: status >= 40 ? 20 : 0,
                      resizeMode: 'cover',
                    })}
              </View>)
            ))}
          </View>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: status >= 40 && 'space-evenly' }}>
          {item.images.slice(2, 4).map((image, index) => (
               image !== null && (
              <View key={index} style={{ marginRight: status >= 40 && index === 2 ? 20 : 0 }}>
                {renderImage(image, status,
                  {
                    height: status >= 40 ? 150 : 120,
                    width: status >= 40 ? 180 : 133,
                    marginRight: status >= 40 ? 10 : 0,
                    resizeMode: 'cover',
                  })}
              </View>)
            ))}

 <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: status >= 40 && 'space-evenly' }}>
                    {subItem.images.slice(0, 2).map((image, index) => (
                      image !== null && (
                         <View key={index} style={{ marginRight: status >= 40 && index === 0 ? 20 : 0 }}>
                         {renderImage(image, status,
                          {
                            height: status >= 40 ? 120 : 120,
                            width: status >= 40 ? 160 : 133,
                            marginRight: status >= 40 ? 20 : 0,
                            resizeMode: 'cover',
                          })}
                       </View>)
                        ))}
                        </View>
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: status >= 40 && 'space-evenly' }}>
                        {subItem.images.slice(2, 4).map((image, index) => (
                          image !== null && (
                            <View key={index} style={{ marginRight: status >= 40 && index === 2 ? 20 : 0 }}>
                              {renderImage(image, status,
                                {
                                  height: status >= 40 ? 120 : 120,
                                  width: status >= 40 ? 160 : 133,
                                  marginRight: status >= 40 ? 20 : 0,
                                  resizeMode: 'cover',
                                })}
                            </View>)
                          ))}
                        </View>

I'm considering using useMemo to optimize image rendering, but due to the dynamic nature of passing items with arrays of images, I'm struggling to achieve strict sequential loading. How can I ensure that images are loaded one after another in the specified order, especially when passing an object with an array of multiple images?
```